# How to get model fields plus their relations in django?

Tags: python, django, dictionary

With the following code I can get dict of fields in a list:

```
from django.db import connection

table_info = []
tables = connection.introspection.table_names()
seen_models = connection.introspection.installed_models(tables)
for model in seen_models:
    table = model._meta.db_table
    columns = [field.column for field in model._meta.fields]
    table_info.append((table, columns))
```

From the above I can get a json encoded file like:

```
["account_profile",["id","avatar","owner_id","forums","forum_threads","lct_discussion","organization_id","created_at","updated_at"]]
```

Note `owner_id` is a related item, I would like to pull all the related items and create a nested array as a result. I'm not sure how I can modify the above code to achieve this. Any recommendation?

Comment: Have you checked [django-report-builder](https://github.com/burke-software/django-report-builder)? I don't know if it suits your needs but it is a useful tool.

Comment: Checked it out but I don't like the UI. I would like something that blends well with my admin UI design and not appearing totally a different thing. I feel it is not that simpler too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it this way:

```
    table_info = []
    tables = connection.introspection.table_names()
    seen_models = connection.introspection.installed_models(tables)
    for model in seen_models:
        table = model._meta.db_table
        columns = [field.column for field in model._meta.fields]

        # Identify a related field item:
        # Use this to get the related table details
        # Loop the table details and append the columns to the main table columns
        # Results to a nested list with depth of 1
        for field in model._meta.fields:
            if field.get_internal_type() == "ForeignKey":
                related_obj = field.rel.to
                related_table = related_obj._meta.db_table
                columns.append((related_table, [x.column for x in related_obj._meta.fields]))

        table_info.append((table, columns))
```

Note: I did not want to do it recursively to avoid circular relation as mentioned by @ahumeau. This works well for my needs for now. It give me a depth of 1, i.e doesn't look further of the first item.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [Field.is_relation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.is_relation) to check if a field is a relation to another model and inspect the fields of [Field.related_model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.related_model) the same way you do here.

I think the best solution would be to write a recursive function but beware of circular relations between models.